Need to lookup value in multiple columns, return value in another column each time the first value appears



Truck Number
Job1
Job2
Job3




71
5928
5928
5928


72
3958
5928
2971


73
2971
5928
2971



This table is filled in automatically from our daily dispatch sheet to break down a driver's route. In my table, each truck number gets a row, and each job they complete gets a column. I need to be able to fill in a separate table where the job number is the column header (these are be permanent values) with each truck number that ran that job below. the truck number needs to be returned as many times as the job number appears.
For this example, this data set should return:



2971
3958
5928




72
72
71


73

71


73

71




72




73



The order these appear in is not important, but if the value appears multiple times, the truck number must be returned multiple times.
I have tried every lookup, match, and index formula I can think of and I can't seem to find anything that will search multiple columns to do what I need or, if it does, it wont return the value multiple times.
I'm open to a VBA option, but for the most part, my experience there is limited to copy/paste & clear functions. Thanks in advance for any help!

Using Dynamic array formula:
=LET(
    rng,B2:D4,
    trk,A2:A4,
    title,SORT(UNIQUE(TOROW(rng),TRUE),,,TRUE),
    ptbl,DROP(REDUCE("",title,LAMBDA(z,y,HSTACK(z,TOCOL(IF(rng=y,trk,NA()),3)))),,1),
    tbl,VSTACK(title,ptbl),
    IF(ISERROR(tbl),"",tbl))



absolutely would have never been able to find this myself. Thank you so much!

Here is another alternative way using MAKEARRAY() function:


=LET(
     a,A2:A4,
     b,B2:D4,
     c,MAX(COUNTIFS(b,b)),
     ub,SORT(UNIQUE(TOROW(b),1),,,1),
     VSTACK(ub,MAKEARRAY(c,COLUMNS(ub),LAMBDA(r,c,
               IFERROR(INDEX(TOCOL(IF(INDEX(ub,,c)=b,a,NA()),2),r),"")))))



Thanks for that! Would you say one is less cpu intensive than the other? This sheet is massive so I like to keep things as light as possible

@ZackaryChairvolotti for me both works efficiently and smoothly i don't find any problem at all.
